# How to group selector in CSS for two different input types

Tags: html, css

Here I have two different `<input>` types, "text" and "password" and I have these same styles for both of them.
How to group them?

```
input[type=text] {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    color : green;
}

input[type=password] {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    color : green;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
input[type=text], input[type=password] {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    color : green;
}
```

More information: http://www.htmldog.com/guides/css/intermediate/grouping/

Comment: Thank you for a such a quick answer! It works!

Comment: @user3375257 no problem ;) When you ask something in SO, don't forget to mark your questions as answered: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147531/how-mark-my-question-as-answered-on-stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do that. One of the simple solutions is to put a CSS class on both of the Input tags as below.

```
<input type="text" class="formatter" />
<input type="password" class="formatter" />
```

Then put style for that class as below.

```
input.formatter {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    color : green;
}
```